# Python - start a process separated from main py file

Tags: python, process, console

I have a python script .py that basically do this

```
<take input from console>
<launch command with os.system>
<quit console>
```

The problem is that when I launch command with os.system(string), it is executed in the python script, so it will quit console only when the command has finished.
I want launch the command as another process, so the main code goes on and can quit console (with "quit", I guess), without touching the process it started. How can I?

Comment: This is something of a multi-thread/multi-process concept. Please learn on multithread, multiprocessing, and subprocess modules.

Answer (score 0):

The command given to `system()` *is* launched as a separate process, but `system()` waits for its termination.  The easiest way to avoid this is by appending a `&` to your command string, then the command is executed in the background (i. e. without waiting for its termination):

```
system('./call_my_lengthy_program.sh &')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

```
# useless example
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("sleep.exe 5 && echo test", shell=True)
exit(0)
```

.. this will wait 5 seconds and print test to your stdout.